# How to use the RichFaces calendar dayClassFunction in client mode?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

Richfaces allows to specify a custom JavaScript function via the `dayClassFunction` attribute to control the CSS classes of days:

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.4.Final/vdldoc/rich/calendar.html

Yet this doesn't work in client mode, only after a full server roundtrip the styling gets updated. By doesn't work I mean the function isn't even  being called until a server roundtrip occurs.

How would one enable it in client mode?

Comment: What do you mean by client mode? The attribute is set up in the JSF page, are you trying to switch to a different function on the client side?

Comment: No I mean it only works when there is an onchange AJAX request enabled via <a4j:ajax event="change" ..> or after the form is submitted.  It doesn't work when it is purely used client side without AJAX request upon selecting a new date.

Comment: I still don't understand, when you open the page with the calendar are the days not styled? You should show some code either way.